# Wifi hardware blocked (Lenovo G560)

Tags: 12.04, wireless, hardware, lenovo

```
~$ lspci | grep Network
06:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation WiMAX/WiFi Link 5150

~$ rfkill list all
 0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
 1: i2400m-usb:1-1.1:1.0: WiMAX
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
 2: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: yes

~$ sudo rfkill unblock all
```

But WiFi is still disabled.
Here is some info:

```
~$ sudo lshw -class network
  *-network DISABLED      
        description: Wireless interface
        product: WiMAX/WiFi Link 5150
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 00
   serial: 00:16:eb:2b:1d:90
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.2.0-37-generic firmware=8.24.2.2 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
```

I tried also:

1. Default all BIOS settings.
2. Removing the battery.

It worked couple of days ago, but now I really don't know what to do. Can someone help me?

UPDATE:

```
~$ dmesg | grep iwl
[   14.184885] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: found PCI INT A -> IRQ 10
[   14.184885] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: sharing IRQ 10 with 0000:00:1c.0
[   14.184885] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: sharing IRQ 10 with 0000:00:1c.4
[   14.184885] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: sharing IRQ 10 with 0000:01:00.1
[   14.184885] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: setting latency timer to 64
[   14.184885] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: pci_resource_len = 0x00002000
[   14.184885] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: pci_resource_base = ffffc90002184000
[   14.184885] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: HW Revision ID = 0x0
[   14.184885] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: irq 19 for MSI/MSI-X
[   14.184885] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Detected Intel(R) WiMAX/WiFi Link 5150 ABG, REV=0x44
[   14.184885] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
[   14.204887] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: device EEPROM VER=0x223, CALIB=0x4
[   14.204887] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Device SKU: 0Xb0
[   14.204887] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Valid Tx ant: 0X1, Valid Rx ant: 0X3
[   15.048939] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Tunable channels: 13 802.11bg, 24 802.11a channels
[   15.048939] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio.
[   15.104943] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: loaded firmware version 8.24.2.2
```

Here is modules:

```
~$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
vesafb                 13844  1 
joydev                 17693  0 
ums_realtek            18248  0 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     32474  4 
uas                    18180  0 
arc4                   12529  2 
nvidia              12319264  52 
i2400m_usb             36569  0 
i2400m                108026  1 i2400m_usb
wimax                  34762  1 i2400m
rfcomm                 47604  12 
bnep                   18281  2 
parport_pc             32866  0 
ppdev                  17113  0 
binfmt_misc            17540  1 
snd_hda_codec_conexant    62358  1 
snd_hda_intel          33773  7 
snd_hda_codec         127706  3             snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              17764  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                97275  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
uvcvideo               72627  0 
videodev               98259  1 uvcvideo
v4l2_compat_ioctl32    17128  1 videodev
btusb                  18332  2 
bluetooth             180153  23 rfcomm,bnep,btusb
psmouse                97485  0 
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
snd_rawmidi            30748  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
mac_hid                13253  0 
serio_raw              13211  0 
iwlwifi               397059  0 
mac80211              506862  1 iwlwifi
cfg80211              205774  2 iwlwifi,mac80211
snd_seq                61929  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_timer              29990  3 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14540  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
snd                    79041  22     snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
mei                    41616  0 
soundcore              15091  1 snd
snd_page_alloc         18529  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
lp                     17799  0 
parport                46562  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
usb_storage            49198  1 ums_realtek
usbhid                 47238  0 
hid                    99636  1 usbhid
r8169                  62154  0
```

Comment: Have you tried pressing Fn-F(something), where F(something) is the key with a tiny symbol of antenna? Most laptops have either that, or a dedicated wifi button.

Comment: Yeah, I tried Fn+F6 (F6 is a wireless switcher) - still the same. And one more thing - I have a physical switcher on my laptop, but its not working too.

Comment: @Rinzwind I found this in `lsmod` - `wimax 34762 1 i2400m` and `iwlwifi 397059 0`. Checked `dmesg | grep iwl` - no notices like unsupported, please see update in question.

Comment: It must be something really stupidly simple but I am not seeing it :X sorry. It all looks ok to me.

Comment: @Rinzwind Yup, and this is the main problem...

Answer (score 0):

This issue related to the in-efficency of wifi linux driver . If you have another operating system (such as windows 7,8 ..) **log in to that operating system and turn the wifi switch on using fn + F6** . After enabling wifi adapter in windows , reboot the system and log into ubuntu . Then you can use the wifi functionality.

Cheers 
*Ubuntu geek*

Comment: Thank you for reply, but I installed only Ubuntu. Is there any other solutions I can try? Or I should install Windows as dual boot and nothing else will help me solve this case?

Comment: Please try loading a module: sudo modprobe ideapad-laptop. Now try the switch. Also try: sudo rfkill unblock all. If that helps, and there are no other negative consequences, we can add it to /etc/modules so it loads automatically on boot.

Comment: Did you check the BIOS settings for enabling wifi adapter ?

Comment: @chili555 Tried, unfortunately its not working.

Comment: @ubuntu_geek Yeah, adapter is enabled in BIOS.

Comment: I dont know this works or not, try to connect with your machine to internet using ethernet . then use the FN + F6 . sometimes the wifi can enable .Check it.